# Using BETWEEN SYMMETRIC for checking 2 row value expressions

Tags: sql, postgresql, resultset, between

I would like to compare two columns values from `Table-1` (say `colA, colX`) to check if these are in the range of values for columns in `Table-2` (say `colB, colD, colY, colZ`). That's, if `colA` is between `colB-colD`, and/or `colX` is between `colY-colZ` respectively.

I understand `BETWEEN SYMMETRIC` is used when order is irrelevant, e.g. (min, max) or (max,min). Below is the example I created.

TABLES:

```
CREATE TABLE location (id int, lat float, lon float, gpstime int);
CREATE TABLE trips( trip_id int, lat_start float, lat_end float,
               lon_start float, lon_end float, travel_mode text);
```

TABLE VALUES:

```
INSERT INTO location
SELECT 1, 41.2, 8.3, 11111 UNION ALL   --both lat and lon in the interval
SELECT 2, 43.3, 8.5, 22222 UNION ALL   --only lat meets criteria
SELECT 3, 44.0, 8.5,  33333            --only lon meets criteria

INSERT INTO trips
SELECT 1, 41.1, 41.9, 8.0, 8.8, 'foot' UNION ALL  
SELECT 2, 43.1, 43.5, 9.5, 8.9, 'bus' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 42.1, 42.8, 8.7, 8.0, 'metro'
```

**TASK:**

The goal is to get all rows for which either `lat` or `lon` (or both) in `location` table happen to satisfy the criteria (in `trips` table): `lat` between `lat_start-lat_end`; `lon` between `lon_start- lon_end`.

Clearly all rows of `location` table should be returned: row 1 meets all and rows 2 and 3 meet either criteria.

Expected result:

```
+---------+-----------+------+-----+-------------+
| trip_id | timestamp | lat  | lon | travel_mode |
+---------+-----------+------+-----+-------------+
|       1 |     11111 | 41.2 | 8.3 | foot        |
|       2 |     22222 | 43.1 | 8.5 | bus         |
|       3 |     33333 | 44.0 | 8.5 | metro       |
+---------+-----------+------+-----+-------------+
```

So I tried different queries using `BETWEEN SYMMETRIC` but the results aren't correct.

Query-1:

```
SELECT trip_id, gpstime AS timestamp, lat, lon,  travel_mode
FROM location 
INNER JOIN trips 
   ON (lat BETWEEN SYMMETRIC lat_start AND lat_end) 
   AND (lon BETWEEN SYMMETRIC lon_start AND lon_end)
```

Query result:

```
+---------+-----------+------+-----+-------------+
| trip_id | timestamp | lat  | lon | travel_mode |
+---------+-----------+------+-----+-------------+
|       1 |     11111 | 41.2 | 8.3 | foot        |
+---------+-----------+------+-----+-------------+
```

Query-2: messed up everything

```
SELECT trip_id, gpstime AS timestamp, lat, lon,  travel_mode
FROM location 
INNER JOIN trips 
   ON (lat, lon) BETWEEN SYMMETRIC (lat_start,  lat_end) AND (lon_start, lon_end)
```

Result:

```
+---------+-----------+------+-----+-------------+
| trip_id | timestamp | lat  | lon | travel_mode |
+---------+-----------+------+-----+-------------+
|       2 |     11111 | 41.2 | 8.3 | foot        |
|       3 |     11111 | 41.2 | 8.3 | metro       |
+---------+-----------+------+-----+-------------+
```

Query-3: worst even

```
SELECT trip_id, gpstime AS timestamp, lat, lon,  travel_mode
FROM location 
INNER JOIN trips 
   ON lat BETWEEN SYMMETRIC lat_start AND lat_end
UNION 
SELECT trip_id, gpstime AS timestamp, lat, lon,  travel_mode
FROM location 
INNER JOIN trips 
   ON lon BETWEEN SYMMETRIC lon_start AND lon_end
```

Result:

```
+---------+-----------+------+-----+-------------+
| trip_id | timestamp | lat  | lon | travel_mode |
+---------+-----------+------+-----+-------------+
|       1 |     11111 | 41.2 | 8.3 | foot        |
|       1 |     22222 | 43.3 | 8.5 | foot        |
|       1 |     33333 | 44   | 8.5 | foot        |
|       2 |     22222 | 43.3 | 8.5 | bus         |
|       3 |     11111 | 41.2 | 8.3 | metro       |
|       3 |     22222 | 43.3 | 8.5 | metro       |
|       3 |     33333 | 44   | 8.5 | metro       |
+---------+-----------+------+-----+-------------+
```

**Question:** What is the correct query to achieve the desired result?

**EDIT:**

Based on answers received, recommending use of `OR` instead of `AND` in Query-1, I edit my question below to show the result of the recommended query:

QUERY:

```
SELECT trip_id, gpstime AS timestamp, lat, lon,  travel_mode
FROM location 
INNER JOIN trips 
   ON (lat BETWEEN SYMMETRIC lat_start AND lat_end) 
   OR (lon BETWEEN SYMMETRIC lon_start AND lon_end);
```

And here goes the query results:

```
+---------+-----------+------+-----+-------------+
| trip_id | timestamp | lat  | lon | travel_mode |
+---------+-----------+------+-----+-------------+
|       1 |     11111 | 41.2 | 8.3 | foot        |
|       3 |     11111 | 41.2 | 8.3 | metro       |
|       1 |     22222 | 43.3 | 8.5 | foot        |
|       2 |     22222 | 43.3 | 8.5 | bus         |
|       3 |     22222 | 43.3 | 8.5 | metro       |
|       1 |     33333 | 44   | 8.5 | foot        |
|       3 |     33333 | 44   | 8.5 | metro       |
+---------+-----------+------+-----+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

> The goal is to get all rows for which either lat or lon (or both) in
>   location table happen to satisfy the criteria

Replace `AND` with `OR` in your first query.

Comment: That generates something similar to Query-3, yielding 7 rows.

Answer (score 0):

The query you are looking for is

```
SELECT trip_id, gpstime AS timestamp, lat, lon,  travel_mode
FROM location 
INNER JOIN trips 
   ON (lat BETWEEN SYMMETRIC lat_start AND lat_end) 
   OR (lon BETWEEN SYMMETRIC lon_start AND lon_end);
```

like Salman said, but let me help you clear up the misunderstanding.

#### What does `BETWEEN SYMMETRIC` mean?

```
x BETWEEN SYMMETRIC a AND b
```

is the same as

```
x BETWEEN SYMMETRIC LEAST(a, b) AND GREATEST(a, b)
```

So it just swaps boundaries if appropriate.

#### What does `(a, b) < (c, d)` mean?

Comparing tuples is done in a lexicographic fashion.

First, `a` and `c` are compared, and only if they are equal, `b` and `d` are compared.

So

```
(a, b) < (c, d)
```

is the same as

```
a < c OR (a = c AND b < d)
```

So that is not what you are looking for at all.

Comment: Using `OR` generates results similar to query-3. I edit my question to show it with generated results.

Comment: Yes. And that is exactly the "task" you describe in your question.

Comment: I would like to get the result set that is shown in the "Expected Result" part of my question.

Comment: Oh, now I see. You think that the first row of the one table is joined with the first row of the other table and so on. You should read about SQL joins. Explaining all that by far exceeds the format of a Stackoverflow answer. For one, table rows don't have an ordering, so "the first row in a table" doesn't have a clear meaning.